# Cartoon series about a boy having nightmares

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon series where the entire concept is based around the main protagonist, a young boy with glasses (whom I'll just refer to as boy for simplicity sake), having crazy nightmares.

Some episodes I faintly remember:

- Boy went to see a movie in the cinema with his girlfriend, I think, or maybe just a random girl from his class who has a crush on him. He falls asleep in the middle of the movie, and I think the girl is pissed at him when the episode ends.
- Boy and his family have dinner with... a zombie family. At some point, for some reason, boy turned into a zombie himself and is taken in by the zombie family.
- Boy's father tells him about how things in their house sometimes "move" for various reasons (floor board cracking from drying/decaying or something along those lines, for example) and that he shouldn't be worried. I think boy was mostly worried about a door knob that kept turning for no reason, which he tried to ignore until he finally fell asleep.
- Boy joined some boy scouts group or something. Strangely, he isn't the one who had the nightmare and it's centered around the other boy scout characters instead.

Anyone know what the name of that cartoon series was?

Some more details:

- I think it aired late 90's and/or early 2000's.
- I saw it in Switzerland. The channel was a German-speaking one.
- I don't remember which channel I saw it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the 1997 series *[Nightmare Ned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightmare_Ned)*. If you saw it in German it might have been known as *Neds Bösenachtgeschichten*.

*a cartoon series where the entire concept is based around the main protagonist, a young boy with glasses (whom I'll just refer to as boy for simplicity sake), having crazy nightmares.*

The title card below shows this young boy and he does indeed have glasses on.

[image: Nightmare Ned title card]

The linked Wikipedia page also has this to say of the younf boy.

> **Ned Needlemeyer**: The show's protagonist. He is a 10-year-old boy who deals with his troubles through his nightmares.

*Boy went to see a movie in the cinema with his girlfriend, I think, or maybe just a random girl from his class who has a crush on him. He falls asleep in the middle of the movie, and I think the girl is pissed at him when the episode ends.*

*Boy and his family have dinner with... a zombie family. At some point, for some reason, boy turned into a zombie himself and is taken in by the zombie family.*

Both of these descriptions are for the episode entitled "Until Death Do Us Part". You can see it below.

*Boy's father tells him about how things in their house sometimes "move" for various reasons (floor board cracking from drying/decaying or something along those lines, for example) and that he shouldn't be worried. I think boy was mostly worried about a door knob that kept turning for no reason, which he tried to ignore until he finally fell asleep.*

This sounds like "House of Games", the doorknob moving is even in the opening scene.

*Boy joined some boy scouts group or something. Strangely, he isn't the one who had the nightmare and it's centered around the other boy scout characters instead.*

This would appear to be "Headless Lester".